Python Tkinter pop up runs, but only sometimes shows up
My Tkinter pop_up method seems to run as expected on its own, and placed in alternative lines in the method that calls it. But when placed in the places its needed the pop up doesn't show. Its seen to run with debuging print out, but does not pop up.
    def pop_up(self, instruction):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("500x250")
        root.title("Cheese Time")

        def button_command():
            global instruction_exe_time
            t = strptime(entry.get()) # timeobject
            instruction_exe_time= mktime(t) # time in seconds
            self.set_time(instruction[0],instruction_exe_time)
            print(ctime(instruction_exe_time))
            root.destroy() 

        label_instruction = Label(root, text = instruction[1][0], font=('Helvetica 12 bold'))
        label_instruction.pack(pady=20)
        label = Label(root, text = "Enter time of execution:", font= ('Helvetica 10 bold')) 
        label.pack(pady= 10)

        entry = Entry(root, width = 22, font=('Helvetica 14 bold'))
        entry.insert(10,f"{ctime()}")
        entry.pack(pady=10)

        button = Button(root, text= "OK", command=lambda:button_command(), font= ('Helvetica 14 bold'))
        button.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
        root.mainloop()`

    # @threaded              
    def make_cheese(self):
        print("Press enter to continue or 'A' to enter time of execution")
        
        for instruc in self.instructions.items():
            # self.pop_up(instruc) pop_runs when placed here also makes other pop_up calls run
            if instruc[1][1] == True:
                self.sleep_adjust(instruc[0])
                #sleep(10) #instruc[1][2]
                print(instruc[0], ": ", instruc[1][0])
                self.pop_up(instruc) # does not work here 
            else:
               # self.pop_up(instruc) pop_up also runs properly when placed here and makes other pop_ups run
                print(instruc[0], ": ",instruc[1][0])
                input1 = input()
                
                if input1 == "A" or input1 == "a":
                    self.pop_up(instruc) # does not work here
                else:
                    self.set_time(instruc[0],time())
            self.set_done(instruc[0])

The pop_up method when placed in alternative parts of the method that calls it, runs it and then runs the other calls properly in the place where its needed.
What is it that is stopping it from showing?

do you use threads ? Most GUIs don't like to work in threads and it may need to send message to main thread (ie. using queue) and main thread should display or change GUI.

Here, do not create multiple instances of Tk(), as it is meant only to be made once. Instead, to create multiple windows, use Toplevel() to create instances.
Hope that helps!
